# Удаление узлов XML

Tags: sql, база-данных, xml, sql-server, dom

Допустим имеет XML вида:

```
<root>
<n>
<t></t>
<t></t>
<t></t>
</n>
<n>
<t></t>
<t></t>
</n>
</root>
```

Можно ли без использования цикла в MS SQL удалить все узлы `(root/n/t)[n]`, где `n > 1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SET @doc.modify('delete /root/n/t[position()>1]')
```